# Is <Button android:alpha="0.5"... API version 11+?

Tags: android

The java `setAlpha()` method says that it is API level 11. but the XML side of it does not say anything and when I use it, it is not picked up in Lint as a warning since I have specified min SDK 8.

Will it crash on 2.2 if I use   android:alpha="" ?

Comment: @eric you mean on an emulator? good idea I usually don't use emulator. I will try that now

Answer (score 2):

You can provide alpha values in background property if you are planning to use a color as background.

```
    android:background="88000000"
```

will make it partially transparent. First 2 values will be considered as alpha values if you provide 8 characters for color.

Comment: Don't forget to use the # sign, like: android:background="#77F0F8FF"